# DropShadowFilter Crops Bitmaps in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am applying a `DropShadowFilter` to a Bitmap in an Adobe AIR 3.5, ActionScript 3 Mobile project. For the most part, it works fine. Every now and then, however, an image is cut off slightly either on the bottom or the right side.

See these images:

[image] vs [image]

As you can see, both the right side and bottom are cropped when applying the drop shadow. Is there a reason for this? Or a way to fix it?

**EDIT (10:30AM MST 2-27)**: As a quick update, it also occurs with the `BlurFilter` and, presumably, any other filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when the `Bitmap` is at a non-integer x or y position. It seems to be a bug in how the source data is passed to the filter, and I couldn't find a good solution trying out different `Bitmap`'s `pixelSnapping` and `smoothing` properties.

You could keep the image aligned exactly by rounding its global position (See [`localToGlobal`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29) and [`globalToLocal`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#globalToLocal%28%29), but if it moves it might be easier to wrap the `Bitmap` in a `Sprite` with a slightly larger transparent background, to force the filter to include a safety margin around the edge. Something like this:

```
private var b:Bitmap = new EmbeddedClass();
private var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
container.addChild(b);
container.graphics.beginFill(0xFF00FF, 0);
container.graphics.drawRect(-2, -2, container.width + 4, container.height + 4);
container.graphics.endFill();
container.filters = [new DropShadowFilter()];
```

Alternatively, you could draw the source `BitmapData` to a slightly larger copy to do the same thing.

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I was hoping to see. Well... not exactly. It sucks that I'll have to work around the damn SDK, but at least it is fixable. Only bad part is that I have hundreds of images in this project. I'll have to make a custom Bitmap class that does this automatically, I think. Damnit, Flash. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're generating the Bitmap, but if you're using the BitmapData class use the handy [**generateFilterRect()**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#generateFilterRect%28%29) function which will compute the new bounds with the passed filter applied.

This should give you the correct dimensions, especially when using BlurFilter or BevelFilter which extend the appearance of the object. Have a look at the example bellow the method description as well.

Comment: It's actually an embedded image. I embed and just do a `var b:Bitmap = new EmbeddeClass();`